# Using a square wave function to select output

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, bjt, square

Im new here!

I been having some trouble thinking about a circuit wich **selects** one of two outputs based in the value of a square wave function like this
[image: Input//Output]

To put some numbers
Freqs

Vin=1Hz

Vout1=1kHz

Vout2=5kHz

without using any type of logic gates, I've tried with op amps, bjt, and some jfets ideas without success. Is there any generic type of circuits that I can study to make this work?

Thanks a lot

Comment: a SPDT relay  ...

Comment: I'm not sure it's helpful to your problem statement to call the selection input a "square wave function", as this just seems to needlessly complicate the description. It's really just a binary (2 state) input - the fact that you might drive it with a square wave doesn't really have any impact on its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use a single pole double throw (SPDT) analog switch IC such as [this](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PI5A3157.pdf)

Select which input (B0 or B1) is connected to the output A by the logic level of S.

Make sure the signal is in range of the chip's specifications and power supply though.  There are many different options of a chip like this one.  You may need to choose one to match your power supply, signal bandwidth, and package type.

Comment: And if the OP is morally opposed to integrated circuits they could always build analog switches from MOSFETs.